# Convergence in probability of the inverse of a sequence of random variables.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, random-variables

Let $X_n$ be a sequence of random variables such that $X_n>0$ a.s. for all $n$ and such that $X_n\stackrel{p}{\rightarrow} X$ with $X>0$ a.s.. I want to show that $\frac{1}{X_n}\stackrel{p}{\rightarrow}\frac{1}{X}$.

I found a similar topic here [Convergence in probability inverse of random variable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/577450/convergence-in-probability-inverse-of-random-variable) but it is restricted to the case $X=1$ and I need the most general one.

Comment: Write $Y_n=X_n/X$, and use the referenced link.

Comment: ...or this one: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1117666/